# How to copy files inside the same FileSystem efficiently

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I wrote a job that one of his roles is to copy a lot of very big files inside the HDFS.
I found that using FileUtil.copy() is not efficient.

Is there more efficient way to do it? I heard about DistCp.java is it better then FileUtil.copy()? is there DistCp.java Cloudera implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there DistCp.java Cloudera implementation?

Not sure what you meant by a Cloudera implementation. It's part of standard Hadoop installation, so it should be part of CDH also. You could also use [DistCp](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/distcp.html) command directly. The DistCp command internally invokes DistCp.java class to copy the files.

> I heard about DistCp.java is it better then FileUtil.copy()?

The FileUtil.copy() method is copying the files in a sequence, while DistCp spawns a MR job to copy the files which is more efficient, since the copy happens in parallel. Check the [DistCp](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/distcp.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: there is another copy method which copy files between FileSystems, in other words inside the HDFS:
public static boolean copy(FileSystem srcFS,
                           Path src,
                           FileSystem dstFS,
                           Path dst,
                           boolean deleteSource,
                           boolean overwrite,
                           Configuration conf)
                    throws IOException

    .

Comment: Thnx - I didn't notice the method. I updated my answer accordingly.